# Ansible task continuation only when find strings in registred variable

Tags: ansible

I have Ansible code below

```
- name: Try to delete file
  shell: rm -rf /tmp/"{{ file_Del }}"
  register: result
  ignore_errors: True 

- name: Display result
  debug:
    var: result.stdout
```

result.stdout can be either 
 
"result.stderr": "Error from server (NotFound): file /tmp/somefile not found"

OR 
"result.stderr": "" <= in success

Both of these are valid but I want to fail Ansible of anything else in the "result.stderr". Ex: "result.stderr": "rm -rf Command not found"

How do I do that with "end_play"

```
- meta: end_play
  when: "*Error from server (NotFound): file.*.*not found" not in result.stderr OR result.stderr ==""
```

Comment: Do you only want to use end_play here or any other logic can be used? Is your "when" condition not working for end_play?

Answer (score 0):

*`rm`* isn't very chatty. See [rm -rf return codes](https://superuser.com/questions/631709/rm-rf-return-codes). But it's possible to use *`find`* and *`xargs`*. For example the play

```
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    file_del: xxx
  tasks:
    - shell: "find /tmp/{{ file_del }} | xargs /bin/rm"
      ignore_errors: True 
      register: result
    - meta: end_play
      when: result.rc == 123
    - debug:
        msg: /tmp/{{ file_del }} found and deleted. Continue play.
```

gives (when /tmp/{{ file_del }} found and deleted)

```
"msg": "/tmp/xxx found and deleted. Continue play."
```

and ends the play when file not found *`result.rc == 123`*.

---

Notes

- Make sure rc 123 is reported when file not found
- It's possible to test result.stderr

---

If possible write a custom command. For example

```
$ cat my_custom_command.sh 
#!/bin/sh

if [ "$#" -eq "0" ]; then
   echo "[ERR 123] No files found.";
   exit 123;
fi

echo "Here I can do whatever I want with $@";
exit 0;
```

Comment: Ignoring errors isn't very fashionable, isn't it? Couldn't one simply find files in one task, then at the next task, remove files when found.

Comment: No, it is not. Unless it is for good reason. For example to handle the error codes.

Comment: @Kevin C: What's preventing you from posting your own answer?

Comment: Actual shell command is not "rm", It is a our custom command. So that's why I need to use "find" to find what I have in registered variable and terminate Ansible if I have anything other than `"result.stderr": "Error from server (NotFound): namespaces \"mynamespace\" not found" OR   result.stderr =="" `

Comment: Even better when you have a custom command. What is preventing you from setting the return codes in your custom command?

Answer (score 0):

When looking at this question it looks like you're working in a bit of a mess, and trying to continue in that way. I think it's best to not move further in that direction, but rather work in a more professional fashion.

For now; a more elegant solution, with only using Ansible modules;

```
---
- hosts: local_test
  # gather_facts: False
  vars:
    file_Del: test
  tasks:
    - name: find some files at a location, recursively
      find:
        paths: "/tmp/{{ file_Del }}"
        recurse: true
      register: found_files

    - name: display files found, to be deleted, could be empty
      debug:
        msg: "Files found are {{ item.path }}"
      with_items:
        - "{{ found_files.files }}"

    - name: delete files when found
      file:
        path: "{{ item.path }}"
        state: absent
      with_items: "{{ found_files.files | default ([]) }}"

    - name: display files found, to be deleted, could be empty
      debug:
        msg: "{{ found_files }}"

    - name: end play when no files are found
      meta: end_play
      when: found_files.matched == 0

    - name: this task is skipped when there are no files found, but executed when files were deleted
      shell: echo hi
```

Regarding your matter with `"rm -rf Command not found"`; this looks just out of the ordinary, e.g. you're executing a playbook on both a Linux and a Windows host, where the task would fail on a Windows host. Each Linux host I know of is pre-installed with `rm`, even most Docker containers and OpenBSD hosts.

It could be wise to separate these tasks per environment.

Perhaps a bit of context could help us, and eventually you, out.